# Managing data in tables of MySQL by overwriting existing data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table which holds notices for a university website.I want it to hold a maximum of 1,000 notices.I am using the id field (which is auto increment) to fetch 10 most recent notices (by counting the total entries that denotes current most recent id and then traversing in backward direction by 10)and then next 10 and so on.

Now when the notice reaches the 1000 limit the notice should start getting uploaded from id 1 by overwriting existing data.
Now the problem is how can I modify the `sql` query to identify the most recent notice?Because suppose I uploaded 17 notices after the table was full,then the notices 1 to 17 are the recent notices ,17 being the most recent and next to it i.e 18 is the least recent in the table .

Or is there any tutorial or something specific to  such case or any optimal method?

Here is my table structure-

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title     | varchar(160) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| body      | mediumtext   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| posted_by | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| semester  | int(2)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| branch    | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| posted_on | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: This question is not clear.

Comment: @InsaneCoder consider adding timestamp in table and the fetch records ordered by timestamp

Comment: Whole question. It will be useful if you post some images of your data and desired result, and your tried queries.

Comment: @Let'sCode:Yes that's a good idea,this solves half of the problem .But what should i do when the table is full?

Comment: @InsaneCoder .. what is the problem you think , you will face then ?

Comment: @Let'sCode :What will be the query to insert 1001 th field as I am using the id field which is auto_increment to fetch more information about the notice.

Comment: will you mind posting dummy structure of your table ?

Comment: @Let'sCode:Please see the updated question with dummy structure.

Comment: Now your problem is when your reach 1001 record you want to update the 1st Record .. right ?

Comment: @Let'sCode:One trick which I am getting is to create 2 tables instead of one and start filling into other table when one gets full and similarly keep truncating and filling into alternate tables.

Comment: @Let'sCode:Yes,exactly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32538/discussion-between-lets-code-and-insane-coder)

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ : I want to limit the table by making it circular in nature.Though the title is same but that question addresses a different issue.So you should not downvote a question blindly,please!!!

Comment: @InsaneCoder You're talking about limiting the records for the table. That question has the same answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a delete query after your insertion query. That way you wouldn't need to pull another query to see which record was last updated.

```
insert into table notices...;
delete from notices where id not in (select top 1000 id from notices);
```

If you wanted to keep the same 1000 ids for some reason, then you could switch auto-increment off in the table, then you would have to pull two different queries:

```
select id,min(posted_on) from notices;
update notices set .... where id=$id;
```

Really because MySQL is designed to handle millions of rows, then you don't actually have to do this at all. You can pull a query with a limit of 1000.

```
select * from notices limit 1000 order by posted_on DESC;
```